# Closed subspace of $L^2(1,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I would like to show that a subspace of a Hilbert space is closed.

Let $F$ be the Hilbert space $L^2(1,\infty)$ with the inner product $\langle f_1,f_2\rangle=\int_1^\infty f_1f_2dx$.

Let $L$ be the linear operator which maps real functions on $(1,\infty)$ to an infinite summation of dilated functions multiplied by a negative exponential:

$$L:f\mapsto\sum_{u=1}^{\infty}e^{-u} f_u$$
where $f_u(x)=f(ux)$.

Let $G$ be the image of $F$ under the operator $L$. Please show that $G$ is a Hilbert space.

Here is my attempt: I want to show that $G$ is a closed subspace of $F$

$G$ is a subspace of $F$: Let $c=\int_1^\infty|f(x)|^2dx$ for $f(x)\in F$, and $g(x)=Lf(x)$. We have the following inequalities which show that $\int_1^\infty|g(x)|^2dx$ exists and is finite:

$\int_1^\infty|g(x)|^2dx\leq \sum_{u=1}^{\infty}cue^{-u}<\int_1^\infty cue^{-u}du<\infty$

$G$ is closed: I think i want to show that $G$ is equal to its closure or any convergent sequence of elements in $G$ must have a limit in $G$. Does it suffice to say that convergence of sequences of $L^2(1,\infty)$ implies convergence of subsequences hence $G$ is closed?

thanks

Comment: In the definition of $L$, is it $f(xu)$ or $f(x+u)$? You say translates, but the first version are not.

Comment: hi, yes it is $f(xu)$. i meant multiplicative translations... is there another name for that?

Comment: I've seen rescales of $f$ used. Don't know if it's an "official" name though.

Comment: There is a problem with definition of $L.$ As $L$ is defined on $f\in L^2(1,\infty)$  the point values $f(xu)$ are not well defined.

Comment: Does $ L^2(1,\infty) \cap C_0(1,\infty)$ fix it?

Comment: Yes, it does. But then $L^2\cap C_0$ is not complete.

Comment: If $f \in L^2(1,\infty)$, then $f(xu)$ is defined a.e., so as usual interpret $L(f)$ up to null sets.

Comment: @GEdgar That's right. I would prefer the sum written as $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-u}f_u(x)$$ where $f_u(x)=f(ux).$

Comment: According to GEdgar's comment, I misunderstood the formula, and  you do not need to restrict to the continuous functions. The space $L^2\cap C_0$ is a proper dense subspace of $L^2.$ Therefore it is not closed.

Comment: ah, ok thanks... ill make some edits to the summation. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Sorry for misleading. According to my calculations I got $\|f_u\|_2\le u^{-1/2}\|f\|_2,$ hence $\|Lf\|_2\le \sum u^{-1/2}e^{-u}.$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135297/discussion-between-ryszard-szwarc-and-maxjames).

Answer (score 2):

We are going to show that the operator $L$ is invertible. Let $A_n$ denote the operator defined by
$(A_nf)(x)=f(nx).$ Then
$$\|A_nf\|_2^2=\int\limits_1^\infty |f(nx)|^2\,dx \underset{y=nx}{=}
{1\over n}\int\limits_n^\infty |f(y)|^2\,dy\le {1\over n}\|f\|_2^2$$
Therefore $\|A_n\|\le n^{-1/2}.$ We have
$$L=e^{-1}I +\sum_{n=2}^\infty e^{-n}A_n$$ Hence
$$\|eL-I\|=\left \|\sum_{n=2}^\infty e^{1-n}A_n\right \|\le \sum_{n=2}^\infty e^{1-n}\|A_n\|\le e\sum_{n=2}^\infty n^{-1/2}e^{-n}<e\sum_{n=2}^\infty e^{-n}={1\over e-1}<1
$$
We have shown, in particular, that the operator $L$ is well defined, as the series representing $L$ is absolutely convergent.
Now the conclusion follows from the general theorem, that if $\|T-I\|<1$ then $T$ is invertible. Hence $eL$ is invertible, as well as $L.$ The image of $L$ is equal the entire space, therefore it is obviously closed.

Comment: (+1) That was a very nice and simple trick.

Comment: @Oliver Diaz Thanks.  It's possible to make the problem slightly harder by removing the first term from the series. Then the operator is not invertible.